# How to get the last but not empty line in a txt file

Tags: c++

I want to get the last but not empty line in a txt file.

This is my code:

```
string line1, line2;
ifstream myfile(argv[1]);
if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while( !myfile.eof() )
    {
        getline(myfile, line1);
        if( line1 != "" || line1 != "\t" || line1 != "\n" || !line1.empty() )
            line2 = line1;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else
    cout << "Unable to open file";
```

The problem is I cannot check the empty line.

Comment: Your file reading logic is incorrect. http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/hello-world/ To summarize, the flags are only set *after* you attempt to read, checking `eof` before you read is backwards. The stream overloads a conversion operator anyway, so you should always check the stream state with just `if (myfile)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't be enough to change your ||'s to &&'s to check if the line is empty. What if there are seven spaces, a tab character, another 3 spaces and finally a newline? You can't list all the ways of getting only whitespace in a line. Instead, check every character in the line to see if it is whitespace.

In this code, `is_empty` will be false if any non-space character is found in the line.

```
bool is_empty = true;
for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
    char ch = line[i];
    is_empty = is_empty && isspace(ch);
}
```

Full solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string line;
    string last_line;

    ifstream myfile(argv[1]);
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while( getline(myfile, line) ) {
            bool is_empty = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
                char ch = line[i];
                is_empty = is_empty && isspace(ch);
            }
            if (!is_empty) {
                last_line = line;
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
        cout << "Last line: " << last_line << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Okay, let's start with the obvious part. This: `while( !myfile.eof() )` is essentially always wrong, so you're not going to detect the end of the file correctly. Since you're using `getline` to read the data, you want to check its return value:

```
while (getline(myfile, line1)) // ...
```

Likewise, the logic here:

```
    if( line1 != "" || line1 != "\t" || line1 != "\n" || !line1.empty() )
        line2 = line1;
```

...is clearly wrong. I'm guessing you really want `&&` instead of `||` for this. As it stands, the result is always true, because no matter what value `line1` contains, it must be unequal to at least *one* of those values (i.e., it can't simultaneously contain only a tab *and* contain only a new-line *and* contain nothing at all -- but that would be necessary for the result to be false). Testing for both `!line1.empty()` and `line1 != ""` appears redundant as well.

Comment: Also note it will never contain '\n' as the getline reads a line (terminated by '\n'). The terminating character is NOT added to the string (line1).

Answer (score 5):

Why not read the file backwards? That way you don't have to scan the entire file to accomplish this. Seems like it ought to be possible.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   std::cout<<"Opening "<<fn<<std::endl;
   std::fstream fin(fn.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
   //go to end
   fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
   int currpos = fin.tellg();
   //go to 1 before end of file
   if(currpos > 0)
   {
       //collect the chars here...
       std::vector<char> chars;
       fin.seekg(currpos - 1);
       currpos = fin.tellg();
       while(currpos > 0)
       {
           char c = fin.get();
           if(!fin.good())
           {
               break;
           }
           chars.push_back(c);
           currpos -= 1;
           fin.seekg(currpos);
       }
       //do whatever u want with chars...
       //this is the reversed order
       for(std::vector<char>::size_type i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i)
       {
           std::cout<<chars[i];
       }
       //this is the forward order...
       for(std::vector<char>::size_type i = chars.size(); i != 0; --i)
       {
           std::cout<<chars[i-1];
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How, do you have some advices?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Additional to what the others said:
You can avoid reading whitespace by doing `myfile >> std::ws` before you call `std::getline()`. This will consume all leading whitespaces.

Then your condition reduces to `!line1.empty()`. This would also work when the line contains nothing but *several* whitespaces, for which your version fails.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to google an appropriate get_last_line function for my needs and here's what i came up with. You can even read multiple non-empty last lines by recalling the instream get_last_line func without resetting the seeker. It supports a 1 char only file. I added the reset parameter, which can be set to ios_base::end to allow output operations after reading the last line(s)

```
std::string& get_last_line(
        std::istream& in_stream, 
        std::string& output = std::string(), 
        std::ios_base::seekdir reset = std::ios_base::cur)
{
    output.clear();
    std::streambuf& buf = *in_stream.rdbuf();
    bool text_found = false;

    while(buf.pubseekoff(-1, std::ios_base::cur) >= 0)
    {
        char c = buf.sgetc();
        if(!isspace(c))
            text_found = true;
        if(text_found)
        {
            if(c == '\n' || c == -1)
                break;
            output.insert(0, sizeof c, c);
        }
    }

    buf.pubseekoff(0, reset);
    return output;
}

std::string& get_last_line(
        const std::string& file_name, 
        std::string& output = std::string())
{
    std::ifstream file_in(
        file_name.c_str(), 
        std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::ate);
    if(!file_in.is_open())
    {
        output.clear();
        return output;
    }
    get_last_line(file_in, output);
    file_in.close();
    return output;
}
```